# How to open multiple files with Delphi

Tags: file, delphi

I'm using the code below
but paramstr(i) give only the file exe path paramstr(0), and the filepath paramstr(1)

but if I open multiples files with my delhi app associate paramstr(2) and so on give  me blank, so how Can I get all the files selected to open with my app??

```
procedure Talpha.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
m:IWMPMedia ;
i:integer;
begin

 for i := 1 to ParamCount  do
        //   for i := 0 to ParamCount -1 do
   begin


 m:=WMP1.mediaCollection.add(paramstr(i));

  WMP1.currentPlaylist.appendItem(m);




    except
```

Comment: on windows, when i>0  paramstr(i) operate an extraction of the result of "GetCommandLine" so you should check what GetCommandLine returns in your case when you "open multiple files".

Comment: ParamStr(i) works fine. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I just associate the file with my delphi app, so I select the .avi files and I select open with and I select my app

Comment: In that case the open verb in the registry is possibly malformed. You should have sets of quotes around the executable path/file and the file name parameter. For example `"C:\Program Files\YourFolder\YourExe.Exe" "%1"`. At least that is what the open verb for Notepad++ looks like and Notepad++ sure does open multiple files selected in the Windows Explorer.

Comment: Either that or you may need to allow for multiple instances being started, one for every selected file, and provide for a way to detect a previous instance and tell it to open the file passed to the current instance. Look for questions on SO with regard to preventing multiple instances and passing command line parameters. They should be around.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you're mis-treating "m". I think you need to have a new instance of m for each file that you're opening.